# storing data for a particular time in asp.net mvc 2.0 using session state concept

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using asp.net mvc 2.0 to implement shopping cart application.My situation is ,
I have a order page, there i am adding the products to the Cart.Below it will show the Cart total.Next i will go to the shopping cart page to delete or editing the items.In this page it will show the same cart total as in the Order page.

But once again if i go back to the Order page to order some more products to the cart,the cart total in the order page is showing 0 amount.
This is my Shopping cart controller action method,

public ActionResult ShoppingCart(int eventID)
        {
   Event e = eRepository.GetEvent(eventID);
   var cart = Stalbans.Models.ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

```
 // Set up our ViewModel
```

var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
  {
     CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
      CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
  };
TempData["data"] = cart.GetTotal();
 if (viewModel.CartItems.Count != 0)
 {
List listp = pRepository.GetProductsForEvent(e.EventID);
 foreach (string item in listp)
  {
     ViewData[item] = pRepository.GetProductsWithProdNameAndEventID(e.EventID, item);
   ViewData["sizelist"] = listp; Group g = new GroupRepository().GetGroup(new EventRepository().GetEvent(e.EventID).GroupID);
         ViewData["group"] = g;
 }

if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
 ViewData["returnUrlAfterLogOff"] = HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
 ViewData["EventOrders"] = oRepository.GetOrderedEvents(User.Identity.Name);
 ViewData["eventModel"] = e;

return View(viewModel);

So once i will go to the shopping cart page from the order page and again coming back to the order page it has to show the same cart total.
Actually data is persisted in the cart total but it is not showing .Because if you add one more item its amount will added to the existimng cart total and then shows the current cart total.
So for the first time i click back at that it has to show the already existed cart total in the cart total value.
So what is the best approach to do this .I have to use session state or somewhat please tell me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You might need to store the shopping cart into the session so that products added there are being persisted between page redirects.

Comment: actually the data is stored in the cart total but while coming back it is not appearing.But again if you add a product it will add to the stored cart toatl.

Comment: but my problem is how display stored data between page redirects.

Comment: @Mallikarjuna, if you store a value in a session or TempData it will be available between page redirects. Maybe showing your code will make things much more clear.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `return RedirectToAction("Foo");`?

Comment: i mean,if i am in shopping cart page.Now i want to(if needed) goback to the order page to order one more item to the shopping cart.if i click back i will go to order page  at this point cart total showing 0.So i have to write condition in shopping cart controller in such a way that if i will go back to order page then i have to to assign the TempData to cart total value.

Comment: @Mallikarjuna, I don't understand what you are asking. Code sample please.

Comment: public ActionResult ShoppingCart(int eventID)
 { Event e = eRepository.GetEvent(eventID);
  var cart = Stalbans.Models.ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
  var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
   {
     CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
     CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
 };
 TempData["data"] = cart.GetTotal();
  if (viewModel.CartItems.Count != 0)
  {
    List<string> listp = pRepository.GetProductsForEvent(e.EventID);
   foreach (string item in listp)
 {
 ViewData[item] = pRepository.GetProductsWithProdNameAndEventID(e.EventID, item);
  } ViewData["sizelist"] = listp;

Comment: ViewData["group"] = g;
            }

            if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
                ViewData["returnUrlAfterLogOff"] = HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
            ViewData["EventOrders"] = oRepository.GetOrderedEvents(User.Identity.Name);
            ViewData["eventModel"] = e;return View(viewModel);

Comment: Please edit your original question to include relevant code snippets. The comments section is for comments. Code is not properly formatted and is completely unreadable here.